# In which weak set theory model which has infinte cardinals $\aleph_0$ is not the minimal one?

Tags: set-theory

I understand that there is such a model but couldn't find it.

Comment: The [hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set) don't have infinite cardinal, for example.

Comment: Thanks. edited my question.

Comment: There are several phenomena you could be referring to here and it’s unclear which one you’re interested in. Can you add some details about how you came to understand there is “such a model”?

Answer (score 3):

We need to be accurate.

In almost any reasonable set theory $\aleph_0$ is *always* **the** minimal infinite cardinal, if it exists. It is simply because any smaller cardinality is finite.

What is true is that $\sf ZFC$ proves that it is the *minimum* of all infinite cardinals, but $\sf ZF$ does not prove this. What is possible is that there are infinite cardinals which are not larger than $\aleph_0$, which makes them the cardinality of sets which are (1) infinite, and (2) do not have countably infinite subsets.

We can show that such infinite sets satisfy the property of being Dedekind-finite, that is: every proper subset is strictly smaller in cardinality. So none of these are minimal cardinals.

---

You could argue that we can provide a *different* definition for cardinality, especially for dealing with sets of natural numbers (e.g. consider the context where every set is a set of natural numbers), and have something like asymptotic density kind of cardinals. So $|A|<|B|$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A\cap\{0,\dots,n-1\}}{B\cap\{0,\dots,n-1\}}<1$. We can still define $\aleph_0$ to be $|\Bbb N|$, which now is the maximum cardinal.

But here we are not really studying *set theory* we are studying specific sets. There is no reasonable way to extend this definition to an arbitrary set, since most sets are not sets of natural numbers.

The point here is that cardinality is measured by stripping off any structure on the set. Which means that if your set theory has even a smidgen of recursion inside of it, then it will prove that every subset of $\Bbb N$ is either finite or has size $\Bbb N$. If it cannot do that, then arguably it fails to be a set theory.

Comment: To be *the* minimal one should also be able to prove that there are no other cardinalities that are minimal in the sense that they are infinite and any cardinality that is $\leq$ is either finite or equal. That cardinalities $\leq$ than $\aleph_0$ are either finite or equal to it only means that $\aleph_0$ is *a* minimal infinite cardinal.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Yes, that's true. It is indeed the case, and I will edit that when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What I am looking for is a ZF model with infinite cardinals which are not larger than $\aleph_0.

Comment: @OMGsh Cohen’s original model has this property. There is an amorphous set of reals, which is infinite but Dedekind-finite. (Watch out, some people use “cardinals” to just mean initial ordinals and would recommend you say “an infinite set whose cardinality is not greater or equal to $\aleph_0$.”)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: There can never be an amorphous set of reals, since amorphous sets cannot be linearly ordered. But otherwise the rest is correct.

Comment: @asaf whoops thanks for the correction. An infinite, Dedekind finite set of reals.